# prevent widget from getting installed

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created an app which installs a widget and everything is working fine. But is it possible to make a check, for example with a boolean var, to check if the widget must be installed or not.
So when the value of the var is true the widget will be installed when the app is getting installed. And ofcourse when the boolean var is set to false, the widget won't be installed. Is that possible or not? Or is it that if I want to accomplish that I should delete all the code for my widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on how you make the decision that a widget shouldn't be installed.

My project DevDrawer only has the Widget available for API 11+

I created 2 bools.xml files (1 in values, 1 in values-v11). Inside the bools.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="widgetEnabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now in the manifest, in your widget receiver:

```
android:enabled="@bool/widgetEnabled"
```

I think this works .. been a while since I picked by pre 4.0 device up though.

Comment: That worked fine indeed thanks, but is there also a way to do this during runtime?